# How to call a thread with function with string? C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine

I tried:

```
Thread uiThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Loading));
uiThread.Start("hey");
```

to call the function

```
public void Loading(string state)
```

but I got matches delegate 'System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart'

what do I need to do differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ParameterizedThreadStart` takes an `object` instead of `string`. You will just have to cast it.

```
public void Loading(object state)
{
   string stateString = state as string;
```